# Converting OSM to mapfroge *.map file fails

Tags: android, dictionary, openstreetmap

I'm using osmosis to conver OSM map file to *.map to use with mapsfroge in android. I installed the plugin through these steps:
 1) copy 'mapsforge-map-writer-0.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar' into
  'osmosis/lib/default' directory
 2) Create file 'osmosis-plugins.conf' into 'osmosis/config' directory
 3) Add this line to the file:
    org.mapsforge.map.writer.osmosis.MapFileWriterPluginLoader

Now, when using this line :
`osmosis --rb file=tehran.osm.pbf --mapfile-writer file=tehran.map type=hd`

I got this :

.
.

```
    `Sep 25, 2012 1:01:50 PM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.ActiveTaskManager waitForCompletion
SEVERE: Thread for task 1-rb failed
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.mapsforge.map.writer.osmosis.MapFileWriterTas
k.initialize(Ljava/util/Map;)V
        at crosby.binary.osmosis.OsmosisReader.run(OsmosisReader.java:43)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Sep 25, 2012 1:01:50 PM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis main
SEVERE: Execution aborted.
org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: One or more tasks failed
.
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.Pipeline.waitForComple
tion(Pipeline.java:146)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.run(Osmosis.java:92)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.main(Osmosis.java:37)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Laun
cher.java:329)`
```

.
.
.

The file "tehran.osm.pbf" is inside the "bin" folder. And also I tested that with two other osm and osm.pbf file (downloded from other web sites). The store is same.

Where is the problem?
Is there another way to convert OSM to *.map file?
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the bounding box (bbox) option?

Info is found [here](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/wiki/GettingStartedMapWriter)

...

Write map file for Berlin-Dahlem. Data has been exported as XML from OSM website, so that we must use a bounding box definition:

*$ bin/osmosis --rx file=../data/dahlem.osm --mw file=/tmp/dahlem-high.map bbox=52.4477300,13.2756600,52.4588200,13.2986600*

**Known Pitfalls**

The plugin requires a bounding box definition, which is either included in the data or is given via the command line parameter bbox. Take note that the XML export functionality of the OSM website currently produces invalid bounding box definitions, so that the bbox parameter must be used in this case.

If you installed the plugin into the user home, please make sure that you run osmosis with exactly this user and not with another user (e.g. the root user).

Answer (score 0):

U can concert frim osm to map with --rx Option
Everything is described at mapsforge wiki

Vetter way to add Plugins

Create plugins foldee in osmosis folder add put the jar there